# transform already scaled element

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to scale already scaled element on hover.

Initially, I'm running an animation

```
animation-name: image-animation;
animation-delay: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-fill-mode: forward;
animation-timing-function: ease-out;

@keyframes image-animation {
  to {
      top: -28%;
      transform: scale(.7);
      }
  }
```

Then I want to  scale the same element on hover:

```
:hover {
transform: scale(1.1)
}
```

Transform on `:hover` action works pretty well if the element wasn't transformed before (see the initial animation "image-animation") but don't work in the case described above.

Is it possible to have an initial animation with `transform: scale(...)`, fix the scale parameter and then apply ``transform: scale(...)` on hover?

Comment: quick question, why do you have to put the first transform in an animation instead of as a simple param?

Comment: edited my answer with the working work-around to have a proper transition.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. The reason it's not working is that you can't change a property that is being animated on hover.

To keep the scale at 0.7: 
idk if it's a typo or a mistake but it should be

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

(you are missing the 's')

To apply 'transform: scale(...)' on hover :
you just need to add 'animation: 0;' to ':hover' :

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  animation-name: image-animation;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform-origin: top center;
  background: green;
}
@keyframes image-animation {
  to {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}

.container:hover{
  animation: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

However, your scale is still base on original size and the animation restarts after you hover off since the animation property changes.

Also, you can't have a transition and an animation on the same property, so if you want it to be smoother, it should be two different animation.

But even if you do that, since your first animation has a delay, after the hover, it goes from scale(1.1) to scale(1), waits 1s, then start the animation again.
Looks better without the delay imo, but if you need the delay only for the first time the animation runs,there are options, but I'd need more detail on the rest of the code to find the appropriate a work around.

EDIT : depending on your need, you could have am :after element scale, but it would only scale the color. If that div has child elements, then you could add another one that would contain those and on which you can use  transform(scale) and transition.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  animation-name: image-animation;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
@keyframes image-animation {
  to {
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
}
.content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in;
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.content:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```